# How to send pcl files to printer on windows 7?

Tags: printing, printer-control-language

I have one an application that generates ".pcl" files. Once generated they are saved on a folder on my Windows 7.

How do I send these files to the printer (either network printer or USB connected printer) for printing?

Comment: Maybe http://openpcl.sourceforge.net/ would do what you want.

Comment: I tried looking at it but I do not want to view just print them directly from a command line or something. ... I will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming your ".pcl" files are raw PCL and simply need the contents sending directly to the printer, the way to do this in the olden days with a network printer was to map a local port with `NET USE LPT3: \\SERVER\printer` and then just `COPY /B file.pcl LPT3:`. I’ve no idea whether that will still work in Windows 7, or whether there’s a way to do the same thing for a USB printer.

Comment: Brian Nixon's idea above does work in Win7, but leave the colon off the LPT3 .  Thanks.

Comment: Incredibly odd that a question with this many views and so useful (to me and others) would be off-topic. Sure it's the answer that's gold, but I only found the answer because someone asked the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To send a PCL file to an HP printer when the version of the PCL in the file matches the capabilities of the printer you need to send the file as *raw data*.

**RAWPRN**

In earlier versions of Windows you could use Microsoft `RAWPRN.EXE` utility to send PostScript or PCL directly to a printer capable of interpreting it.

This utility is described in Microsoft [KB138594](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/138594/EN-US/)  article.

**LPR**

Apparently Windows also provides a simple `LPR` utility.

```
LPR -P LaserPrinter1 "-o l" cad_drawing.pcl
```

Here `LaserPrinter1` is the name of the printer, "-o l" indicates raw data stream and `cad_drawing.pcl` is the name of the PCL file.

This utility is described in the Windows Server [command line reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731926.aspx).

Comment: as mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/a/420447/35237), note you may have to enable the Windows feature "LPR Port Monitor" in order to get the `lpr` command

Comment: In my case I am trying to print to a virtual printer on a predefined port (which is not an LPR port) so this method will not work for me as far as I can tell.  Is there a different method?

Comment: @ObiWan did you try specifying the name of your virtual printer with the `-P` option (that is instead of `LaserPrinter1` in the example above)?

Comment: Yes I did and it did not work.  After further researching I discovered this command only works with certain printers that run on a specific port: the LPR port. In my case I have a virtual printer that runs on its own custom port that cannot be changed.  I spent several hours trying to make this work and my conclusion was that it was not going to work for me, but if you can offer a suggestion of how to make it work for my virtual printer, I am interested.